# How to set OUTPUT param for sp_executesql to be a custom table type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to execute `sp_executesql` stored procedure and return a `custom table type` from it.

Is it possible?

**My code is**:

```
DECLARE @sSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tResult AS ttParamValues;

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT .....  add some params in the concatanation';

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @tResultOUT=@tResult OUT;
SELECT * FROM @tResult;
```

I receive error:

> Msg 348, Level 16, State 1, Line 96
>   The table variable "@tResult" can not be passed to a stored procedure with the OUTPUT option.

I read that table have to be declared as `READONLY` but can not figure out how to do it.

Comment: `EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL....` would have returned the result set anyway you do not need to pass any output parameter to return the result set into some sort of variable. if you want to further select from the result set, do it inside your dynamic sql statement.

Comment: Yes, @M.Ali, but I want to use that code in *SQL table value function* and because it must return table type I try to do it through custom table value type. I need that function because I want to `JOIN` it with other tables and extract data. I preffer not to use `global ##` temp tables because I can have problem with isolation.

Comment: You cannot use dynamic sql insdie a User defined function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  A table time parameter is `READONLY`.  Since the value cannot be modified, it makes no sense to specify the parameter as `OUTPUT`, the data returned will always be the value provided.

Consider returning the resultset as data type XML, which can be returned as an output parameter.